# Why don't I see some of the backed up hard drives on backblaze.com?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, online-backup, backblaze

I am looking at some Backblaze account with the 1-Year Version History option activated over 1 year ago. The Backblaze Windows client indicates that at least one file from external hard drives with letters H, I, J, L was uploaded less than 1 year ago:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The full value of the status column is `(Unplugged)`.

However, I don't see the external hard drives with letters H, I, J, L on https://www.backblaze.com/:

[image: Why]

[image]

Why? Why don't I see some of the backed up hard drives on https://www.backblaze.com/?

I tried to change the date in the "view/restore files" screen to an earlier date when those drives were connected and backed up, but that didn't help:

[image]

The  external hard drives with letters H, I, J, L were showing up in Backblaze fine earlier this year.

Comment: What is their policies on external drives? In my experience with similar services, they discontinue supporting, any drive that wasn’t a system drive and exclude a large amount of file types also.

Comment: @Ramhound external drives are included. All drives in the screenshot are external except for C

Comment: What is the full value of the status columns? What file system are these drives? What file extensions are on these drives? None of the files, except the .jar file, I would expect for BackBlaze to support since they are essentially system file extensions.

Comment: @Ramhound  full value of the status columns is `(Unplugged)`. NTFS and exFAT. Files in these drives are diverse: .exe, .jpg, .mp4, .mp3, .docx etc. Should be included in BackBlaze

Comment: So the only reasons I can see for Black Blaze not to synchronize a drive and list it as unplugged is if the drive as files that are not changed very often or the your BB software is out of date.

Comment: [exFAT](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/217665398-Backing-up-External-Hard-Drives) most certainly at play, “Please note that exFAT volumes have a history of issues with both Mac and Windows operating systems. If you are having trouble backing up an exFAT volume, please contact Backblaze Support for assistance.” - So verify these disks have been online in the last 30 days and if so contact Blackblaze support. All of those files were last updated beyond that 30 day timeframe

Comment: “Any drive is detached for more than 30 days, Backblaze interprets this as data that has been permanently deleted and securely deletes the copy from the Backblaze datacenter. The 30-day countdown is only for drives that have been unplugged. There is no countdown for local files.”

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, the account has the 1-Year Version History option activated over 1 year ago, so Backblaze shouldn't delete any files that are less than 1 year old. The drives were showing up in Backblaze fine earlier this year, so I don't think exFAT is causing the issue

Comment: "With Extended Version history, files removed over 30 days ago, or external drives disconnected for longer than 30 days will be retained on our servers; however, if files/drives have not been present for longer than 30 days they will not appear in your current backup view. You can adjust the date and time preferences in your View/Restore Files section to locate data that has been deleted, overwritten, or otherwise removed from the computer being backed up. "
https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035247494-Version-History-FAQ

Comment: @KeithLangmead thanks, you're right, that fixed the issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlgAW.png). Could you please post your comment as an answer? thanks!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Sounds like your in a better position to answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound done, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Keith Langmead](https://superuser.com/users/301919/keith-langmead) [pointed](https://superuser.com/questions/1815009/why-dont-i-see-some-of-the-backed-up-hard-drives-on-backblaze-com#comment2852639_1815009) to [help.backblaze.com](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035247494-Version-History-FAQ):

> With Extended Version history, files removed over 30 days ago, or external drives disconnected for longer than 30 days will be retained on our servers; however, if files/drives have not been present for longer than 30 days they will not appear in your current backup view. You can adjust the date and time preferences in your View/Restore Files section to locate data that has been deleted, overwritten, or otherwise removed from the computer being backed up.

Changing the date in the View/Restore Files section fixed the issue:

[image]

A former Backblaze employee shared the rationale [here](https://redd.it/17lno9x).

Note that [help.backblaze.com](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035247494-Version-History-FAQ) is incorrect. It says:

> if files/drives have not been present for longer than 30 days they will not appear in your current backup view.

It is in fact not 30 days, but 90 days, as former Backblaze CTO [Brian Wilson](https://www.reddit.com/user/brianwski) [stated](https://www.reddit.com/r/backblaze/comments/17lno9x/why_dont_i_see_some_of_the_backed_up_hard_drives/k7kx4tg/), which I confirm: e.g., 69 days for disk `M` on https://i.stack.imgur.com/14LS5.png.